# Загрузить файлы на Spring Boot и отправить письма с вложениями

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, fileupload

Вопрос больше по архитектуре.

Нужно написать сервис на спринг буте, который принимает `json` и одновременно может принимать список файлов-вложений. Из данных в жсон и из файлов собирается емейл, который отправляется получателю. Процесс выглядит так:

- Принять json на рест эндпоинт (возможно, вместе со списком файлов)
- Положить все это в очередь (`activemq`, rabbitmq)
- Доставать данные из очереди и варить из них емейлы (может быть, с вложениями)

Как лучше принимать данные сервисом, если вложения могут весить по 10-20 мб? Принимать огромный `JSON`, в котором вложения закодированы в base64, переконвертировать их и сбрасывать на диск? Или каким-то образом вместе с получением `JSON` получать список `MultipartFile`?

Покажите, пожалуйста, пример походего сервиса.

Для теста я написал такой эндпоинт:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/api/test2", consumes = MediaType.ALL_VALUE)
    public void test(@RequestParam("files")List<MultipartFile> files) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(files);
    }
```

Но при отправке при помощи Insomnia получаю ошибку:

```
Current request is not a multipart request
```

В инсомнии создал post-запрос Multipart и выбрал файл на диске.

Что я сделал не так?

Comment: Я бы использовал multipart request, а не огромные JSON файлы (которые ещё надо будет парсить).  Насчет того, почему не работает - покажите как Вы делаете запрос, скорее всего, он неправильный.

Comment: @Sergi, не знаю, что выбрать. Multipart Request подошел бы, если бы сервис сразу отправлял письмо. Но запросы кладутся в очередь activemq, а файлы надо где-то хранить и как-то связывать с запросами в очереди. Еще нужно разрешать возможные конфликты имен файлов.